# Javascript screen positioning

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 Game (Canvas) - UI Techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599509/html5-game-canvas-ui-techniques)

I have an HTML5 app that uses the browser width and height properties to stretch accordingly and load the appropriate image quality, some mobile phones seem to change these properties dynamically to reflect on the amount of page which is within the screen (while subtracting the height of the menu on top it seems) this makes for extremely jittery graphics.

How can I make the canvas (or a div) have the same aspect ratio of the device as well as height and width which is the size of the screen? (and to hide the browser menu if possible)
Regards.

Comment: No it's not since I have already decided to go with canvas

Comment: <element>.getBoundingClientRect() will help you in combination with a resize handler....